# on change function in plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried to make a function that fires on a change event, but nothing's working. Here's my code:

```
var PayContent = document.querySelectorAll('.details'); 

function OnChange() { 
         var webForm = document.getElementById('webFormWrap');
            webForm.onchange = function(){

              PayContent[0].style.display = "none";
              button.style.cursor = "default";

            document.getElementById('input_field').value = "";

            } 
//        });
    }
```

I've tried calling the function on load and within a set interval; also within the console as well.

Comment: right, where is OnChange being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just call a function `onchange` and expect it to work. You have to add the event listener to the element. (I'm assuming you have it on a `<form id="form">` element):

```
document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("change", OnChange);
```

This will add the `change` event to the element with ID of `form`.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you are hoping to accomplish here, especially since you didn't post any HTML, but this should get you close.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="details" id="hideMe">This element will be hidden</div>
    <form id="webFormWrap" onchange="OnChange()">
        <input type="text">
    </form>
</body>
```

Notice that I added an id "hideMe" to the element you are trying to hide.

JavaScript (externally loaded)

```
function OnChange() { 
    var PayContent = document.querySelectorAll('div.details'); 

         document.getElementById(PayContent[0].id).style.display = "none";
         button.style.cursor = "default";

       document.getElementById('input_field').value = "";  
}
```

JavaScript doesn't require the use of "#" in query selectors.